# How to implement Google like voice chat using Java EE?

Tags: java

How to implement Google like voice chat using Java EE?

Any body know any API that supports voice chat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google uses [xmpp](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/) protocol.

There are a lot of open source XMMP implementations. 
You can get more information from [this](http://www.saint-andre.com/jabber/jsc/) site